# Smooth animations with GDI+ in C++

Tags: c++, animation, winapi, visual-c++, gdi+

I'm having trouble getting simple smooth animations using GDI+ in C++. My current approach is using a WinAPI timer as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm initializing the timer with `SetTimer` with a 15ms interval. Than, when a corresponding `WM_TIMER` event ocuurs, I'm incrementing the upper-left coordinates of a rectengle, calling `InvalidateRect` for the entire screen and drawing the rectengle. The result is movement as expected but with regular flickering (see [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19-XgZUvSy8N7m3DYg34XCN_HsbKmJKhW/view)). This seems to vary with the interval, but it's always there.

The question is how can I modify this approach to achieve smooth animation? Most similar questions I found concern C#, where toolset seems to be a little bit different.

EDIT: Forgot to add - this is a school project, so changing technologies or languages isn't really an option for me.

Comment: Do some research about *double buffering*.

Comment: Invalidate only the part of the window you need to erase and draw in.

Comment: You could use `GetDC()` and then just draw on it, rather than invalidating the whole window.  You would have to erase the background yourself.  This will be much faster than using `InvalidateRect()`.

Comment: Animations are smooth as long as you make sure to do the following. `1` Change the color of each pixel at most once when rendering a new frame. Double-buffering is a simple way to ensure that. `2` Don't assume a Windows timer to tick at a constant rate. Instead, use the timer to trigger a repaint, but do calculate the animation step based on the start time as well as the current time. Use a timer with a timeout of 0 to render as fast as possible.

Comment: The link to the video is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FALSE` flag for `bErase` in `InvalidateRect`.

```
InvalidateRect( hwnd, NULL, FALSE );
```

Or handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` message

```
LRESULT CALLBACK YourWindowProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam )
{
    switch ( msg )
    {
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        // Don't paint background if you are blitting from off screen surface.
        return 1;
    }
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam );
}
```

Or put `NULL` brush in window class (used for `RegisterClass`) definition.