# Win32 Window flickering when drawing with GDI (PE)

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I'm trying to create a win32 semi / transparent window, on which I could draw with another program on it with GDI+ api
When i'm drawing on the main window the line is staying few second on the screen

Even if the double buffering is enabled with WS_EX_COMPOSITED in SetWindowLong

How can i disable this flickering ? I'm pretty sure the problem is from my window because i don't have this problem on other window

**My WinMain**

```cpp
int WINAPI WinMain(
   _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
   _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
   _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = 0;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            0);

        return 1;
    }
    hInst = hInstance;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_POPUP,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        1280, 720,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            0);

        return 1;
    }

    MSG msg;
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_COMPOSITED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0),  (255 * 50) / 100, LWA_ALPHA); //50%
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }return(int)msg.wParam; 
}
```

and my **WndProc**

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here my code for drawing on the main window

```cpp
    while(1){
        DrawLine(ScreenX, ScreenY/2,ScreenX/2 , id, targethdc);
        Sleep(1);
        id++;
        if(id >= ScreenY){
            id=0;
        }

    }
```

```cpp
void DrawLine(float StartX, float StartY, float EndX, float EndY, HDC hdc)
{
    int a, b = 0;
    HPEN hOPen;
    HPEN hNPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(255,0,0));// penstyle, width, color
    hOPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hNPen);
    MoveToEx(hdc, StartX, StartY, NULL); //start
    a = LineTo(hdc, EndX, EndY); //end
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(hdc, hOPen));

}
```

Thx

Comment: *"wich i can draw with a other program"* - That sounds odd. Why do you have a *different* application render onto your window?

Comment: That Sleep(1); seems suspicious. Your drawing code should be in OnPaint(HDC hdc) and it should NOT contain an infinite while(1) loop.

Comment: @SvenNilsson my drawing code is only for testing my application, how can i optimise it ? creating a condition instead of a infinite loop ?

Comment: You need to post messages so that OnPaint gets called repeatedly. There should not be any infinite drawing loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428349/smooth-animations-with-gdi-in-c

Comment: Normally we draw on the WM_PAINT message.

Comment: @Prince2lu use `SetTimer()` to run a message-basdd timer that updates `id` and invalidates the window on each `WM_TIMER` message. In the `WM_PAINT` handler, draw 1 line using the current `id`